# How to ignore dots and other characters during a search in solr

Tags: solr

I have reference numbers inside a solr field which look like this one:

```
L2.816.4.53.2
42010N-0002
42010N/0002
```

Now I want to search for it and get a match for a string without the dots/dashes/slashes as well:

```
L28164532
42010N0002
42010N0002
```

How could I do this with solr? The current search for `ref:L28164532` will not return a result as there is not such a value stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below field type for your field :

```
<fieldType name="text_wd" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
          <!-- Splits words based on whitespace characters --> 
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <!-- splits words at delimiters based on different arguments --> 
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" catenateNumbers="1"/>
          <!-- Transforms text to lower case -->   
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>

        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Here the The `WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory` has many attributes and using those will help you to achieve the desired result. You can read more about the `WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory` [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html)

for example `catenateWords` or `catenateAll` or `catenateNumbers`. Modify the attributes as per requirement. Once you modify, you might need to restart the server. You can do these try and test by using the Solr admin UI.

Comment: I just added the new field type as you suggested to shema.xml and reindexed. Does not return a result if I remove the dots. The example on solr page states that this should be within the analyzer query. What is the difference between the index/query anylyzer and why did you pick the index analyzer?

Comment: Do I need to restart the server? After reindexing it still shows the entry:  "refnumber":"L2.816.4.53.2", within the index. Search without dots returns no result.

Comment: OK, now I am at least getting an error: "Error loading class 'solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory'". .I guess it needs to be loaded in solrconfig, right? Could not find a way so far to enable it. I am running solr 6.4.1

Comment: @merlin : I think 'WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory' is added newly ...could you try with 'WordDelimiterFilterFactory' instead of WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory. WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory is been added with 6.6 version

Comment: Getting closer! Now it works, but my facetes are broken, and show 3 entries for : 178243-test-R: 178243, test, R. Is there a way to keep the facettes like they used to be?

Comment: I think for that you might need to have 2 separate fields with different fieldTypes applied. One field can be used for querying and other can be used for faceting..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185201/discussion-between-merlin-and-abhijit-bashetti).

Comment: Worked out, problem was that I was not using catenateAll but only catenate Words on a string with numbers. Thank you for your help. Only problem remaining now are the tokens showing up in the facettes.